# Modal values are not retained in react js

Tags: reactjs

I have a modal wherein I've radio buttons and toggle buttons. For toggle buttons what happens is when I toggle the modal it reflects but when I close the modal the states are not preserved i.e., states are not retained, the change is not reflecting except to the default once. I don't know where I'm going wrong.

**footer.js**

```
<footer className={"page-footer font-small blue  " 
          + (this.props.dltheme? 
            'darkfooter ' : 'lightfooter ') 
          + (this.props.tglinsetftrp ?
            'ftInsetTransIn ' : (this.props.tgsbclk ? 
                'ftDefTem ' : 'ftInsetOut '))}>                    
  <div className="text-center">© 2018 Copyright:                     
  </div>                    
</footer>
```

**home.js**

```
<Footer 
   dltheme={this.state.tgldlthemep} 
   tglinsetftrp={this.state.tginsetftrp} 
   tgsbclk={this.state.tglsidebarp}
/>
```

**filtermodal.js.js**  I'm using reactstrap modal

```
<Modal
  isOpen={this.state.toggleModal} 
  toggle={this.togglem.bind(this)}
>
  <ModalBody className={this.state.tgthemep ? ' mdlTDCW ':'mdlTLCB '}>
    <Radiolayoutbtns permcldfn={this.permprntfn.bind(this)}/>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-6"> 
          <label>Footer</label>
          <div className="row">
            <Toggleswitch label='Footer' name='Inset' 
              togFooter={this.tgFooter.bind(this)}/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ModalBody>
  </Modal>
```

The other issue with **filtermodal.js** is for radio buttons my need is to select one default, which works. when I select another radio button, the state too is not preserved when as I close the modal the default radio button is selected due to which the selected radio buttons functionality doesn't work. Where am I going wrong?

**RadioButton.js**

```
<Input type="radio" name="radiobtns" value="" defaultChecked/>Default
<Input type="radio" name="radiobtns" value="" 
  onClick={()=>this.props.permcldfn(true)}/>Permanent
```

**togglem tgFooter**  both re toggling states

**`permprntfn`** is the function which set states

```
permprntfn(prmchdp){
    this.setState({permprntp:prmchdp},()=>this.props.flpermanentFn(this.state.permprntp))  
    console.log("--41----",this.state.permprntp)    
}
```

can anyone please help me with this
Any help is appreciated

Comment: you say the state is not preserved. What do you mean by this... is it a specific value in state that is not being changed? is it the modal not being closed or something similar? could you add the code from the `permprntfn` function?

Comment: @c-chavez i'm trying out lemme try a solution found if not ill come back. as well i have updated my code